# Find all close numerical matches in two 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, match

**Update**: I made the solution into a library called [close-numerical-matches](https://pypi.org/project/close-numerical-matches/).

---

I am looking for a way to find all close matches (within some tolerance) between two 2D arrays and get an array of the indices of the found matches. Multiple answers on SO show how to solve this problem for exact matches (typically with a dictionary), but that is not what I am looking for. Let me give an example:

```py
>>> arr1 = [
    [19.21, 19.19],
    [13.18, 11.55],
    [21.45,  5.83]
]
>>> arr2 = [
    [13.11, 11.54],
    [19.20, 19.19],
    [51.21, 21.55],
    [19.22, 19.18],
    [11.21, 11.55]
]
>>> find_close_match_indices(arr1, arr2, tol=0.1)
[[0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 0]]
```

Above, `[[0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 0]]` is returned because element 0 in `arr1`, [19.21, 19.19] is within tolerance to elements 1 and 3 in `arr2`. Order is not important to me, i.e. `[[0, 3], [1, 0], [0, 1]]` would be just as acceptable.

The shape of `arr1` is (*n*, 2) and `arr2` is (*m*, 2). You can expect that *n* and *m* will be huge. Now, I can easily implement this using a nested for loop but I am sure there must be some smarter way than comparing every element against all other elements.

I thought about using *k*-means clustering to divide the problem into *k* buckets and thus make the nested for-loop approach more tractable, but I think there may be a small risk two close elements are just at the "border" of each of their clusters and therefore wouldn't get compared.

Any external dependencies such as Numpy, Scipy, etc. are fine and it is fine as well as to use O(n + m) space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an idea for how to use buckets to solve this problem. The idea is that a key is formed based on the values of the elements and the tolerance level. To make sure potential matches that were in the "edge" of the bucket are compared against other element at "edges", all neighbour buckets are compared. Finally, I modified @Tim Roberts' approach for performing the actual matching slightly to match on both columns.

I made this into a library called [close-numerical-matches](https://pypi.org/project/close-numerical-matches/). Sample usage:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from close_numerical_matches import find_matches
>>> arr0 = np.array([[25, 24], [50, 50], [25, 26]])
>>> arr1 = np.array([[25, 23], [25, 25], [50.6, 50.6], [60, 60]])
>>> find_matches(arr0, arr1, tol=1.0001)
array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]])
>>> find_matches(arr0, arr1, tol=0.9999)
array([[1, 2]])
>>> find_matches(arr0, arr1, tol=0.60001)
array([], dtype=int64)
>>> find_matches(arr0, arr1, tol=0.60001, dist='max')
array([[1, 2]])
>>> manhatten_dist = lambda arr: np.sum(np.abs(arr), axis=1)
>>> matches = find_matches(arr0, arr1, tol=0.11, dist=manhatten_dist)
>>> matches
array([[0, 1], [0, 1], [2, 1]])
>>> indices0, indices1 = matches.T
>>> arr0[indices0]
array([[25, 24], [25, 24], [25, 26]])
```

Some profiling:

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numpy as np
from close_numerical_matches import naive_find_matches, find_matches

arr0 = np.random.rand(320_000, 2)
arr1 = np.random.rand(44_000, 2)

start = timer()
naive_find_matches(arr0, arr1, tol=0.001)
end = timer()
print(end - start)  # 255.335 s

start = timer()
find_matches(arr0, arr1, tol=0.001)
end = timer()
print(end - start)  # 5.821 s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with NO loops, but you can do it with ONE loop by taking advantage of the boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np

xarr1 = np.array([
    [19.21, 19.19],
    [13.18, 11.55],
    [21.45,  5.83]
])
xarr2 = np.array([
    [13.11, 11.54],
    [19.20, 19.19],
    [51.21, 21.55],
    [19.22, 19.18],
    [11.21, 11.55]
])

def find_close_match_indices(arr1, arr2, tol=0.1):
    results = []
    for i,r1 in enumerate(arr1[:,0]):
        x1 = np.abs(arr2[:,0]-r1) < tol
        results.extend( [i,k] for k in np.where(x1)[0] )
    return results

print(find_close_match_indices(xarr1,xarr2,0.1))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 0]]
```

Comment: This is good, but it still has a O(nm) runtime. I am sure there must be some algorithm to not have to compare all elements directly. I will mark this as accepted if nothing better comes along.

Comment: Well, this operation is ALWAYS going to have O(nm) runtime.  That's just what the algorithm requires.  You have to compare every `a` to every `b`.  There's no magic there.  A doubly nested loop would have `n*m` in Python time, my loop has `n` in Python and `m` in assembler.  You are hoping to find `n*m` all in assembler, but it's always going to scale as O(nm).

Comment: Remember that `np.add( a1, a2)` is still an O(n) operation, even though it's just one line of Python code.

Comment: Another approach would be to divide the elements into buckets (linear time for each of the arrays) and then only compare the elements in the same bucket, giving ∑_k O(n_k m_k) where n_k and m_k are the elements from each array that arrived in bucket k. However, I am not sure exactly how to accomplish this. This would still be O(nm) if all elements match and therefore are assigned in the same bucket, but in the case where there are very few matches it should be much faster.

Comment: After further inspection, it seems like this also ignores the second column entirely.

Comment: You didn't specify anything in your requirements about the second column.  Your examples were all the first column.  Still, all you have to do is change the conditional

Comment: The examples are also close in value in the second column. But I apologise for not being explicit enough.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might find the following useful. Might be faster than @Tim-Roberts 's solution because there are no explicit for loops. But it will use more storage.

```
import numpy as np

xarr1 = np.array([
    [19.21, 19.19],
    [13.18, 11.55],
    [21.45,  5.83]
])
xarr2 = np.array([
    [13.11, 11.54],
    [19.20, 19.19],
    [51.21, 21.55],
    [19.22, 19.18],
    [11.21, 11.55]
])

tol=0.1
xarr1=xarr1[:,None,:]
xarr2=xarr2[None,:,:]
# broadcasting
cc = xarr2-xarr1
cc = np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm,-1,cc)
# or you can use other metrics of closeness e.g. as below
#cc = np.apply_along_axis(np.abs,-1,cc) 
#cc = np.apply_along_axis(np.max,-1,cc)
id1,id2=np.where(cc<tol)
```

Comment: That's going to create an n*m array.  The question specified that the arrays are large.

Comment: Have you done any profiling on this? It seems to be much slower than @Tim Roberts' answer.

Comment: I missed that part in the question where the arrays were specified to be large.  No, I haven't done any profiling. My bad.

Comment: This is not a bad answer, so I'm not downvoting it, but I don't think it solves this particular question.